# Issue with POST method for form email submission

Tags: php, forms, email

I have created an html form using the following code (in HAML):

```
%form#cForm{method: 'post', name:'contactForm', action: 'formEmail.php'}
  %input{type:'text', name: 'name'} Name / Business:
  %input{type: 'text', name:'email'} Your Email:
  %textarea{name: 'message'} Message:
  %input{type:'submit', value:'Send Form'}
```

Here is the php file (formEmail.php):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'david.w.martin@me.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "david.w.martin@me.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
          );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

When I click "submit" I receive the following error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:9000/formEmail.php [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
```

and the following message appears in the browser:

```
Cannot POST /formEmail.php
```

I can, however, access the file directly (by inputting the url into the browser).

The form is located inside a modal popup window (included in the Zurb Foundation framework).

I am lost, please help!!

Comment: Try to give it full path to formEmail.php. It looks like it can find it. If you are using xampp or other local servers then send mail might not work.

Comment: didn't resolve the issue...i tried "http://localhost:9000/formEmail.php" in the action attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `http://localhost:9000/formEmail.php` into the `action` attribute. Maybe that the port gets ignored and it tries to reach `http://localhost/formEmail.php` which is of course a 404.

Comment: Do you use a .htaccess file to rewrite your URLs maybe?

Comment: Do you have the formEmail.php file in your www root folder? Could you tell me the URL which you use to view the html page in which you have the form?

Comment: FormEmail.php is in the document root folder. 

The site is all one page (javaScript used to load the different content areas). The form is located in a modal popup window.

There is an .htaccess file in the document root, but I have not modified it at all. I'm running a test server with Yeoman/Grunt.
Could it simply be that my local test server isn't able to send mail, and it will work fine once the site is live? Or might I need to modify the .htaccess?

Comment: I don't think that it's because your local server can't send a mail. Because you get a 404 page not found error. It says that the formEmail.php does not exist at the location you provided. Could you post the contents of your .htaccess file please? Because if you say that the file formEmail.php is in the correct directory, then i don't know what else could be the problem then the .htaccess file. As i can't see any 404 header being sent by the code in the formEmail.php

Comment: That file is far too big to post here...i could message it to you, or is there something particular I should be looking for? Any particular section I could post here that would be helpful?

Comment: Nope... i just wanted to go through it to see if there is anything that may be causing the problem. Try to remove all .htaccess files (from your root www directory and all subdirectories) and try again.